# Selecting points to create line in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5

Is there way in ArcMap 10.x to select a bunch of points and create a line between all the points?

There is a tool called Connect the Dots for MapInfo Pro that allows you to select any number of points and it will create a line connecting all the points.

Comment: Try tool by Patterson called minimum spanning tree. If there no sharp turns, it will handle all points. Alternatively, use it repeatedly. Points to line is not going to work, unless points physical ly in a right order.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].

Comment: Here is the download link to SpanningTreeTools by Dan Patterson, http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6ce9db93533345e49350d30a07fc913a

Comment: Please describe the requirements that you have for the tool that you seek.  A link to online help for Connect the Dots may be used as background but all information needed to understand the question should be in the question body.  Including a picture would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Points to Line tool. Input your points layer, select a field as the line name if you have, and select a sort field if need be. Will create lines of all points based on the line name field

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/points-to-line.htm

Comment: Points to line won't work.  My points are in a grid layout (horizontal and vertical), the points are not in a straight line and not at same distances between points.  It's a seismic survey and literally several thousand points. There are large gaps where I don't want to connect the points so I will end up having multiple line segments.

Comment: @Gord Details like these belong in the question body, so that answers can address them.